# Gausian Process : Maximum Log-likelihood gives infinite results

Tags: optimization, process, statistics, covariance, gaussian

I feel very dumb not to understand what does not work in this.

I want to fit a Gaussian Process with some data. My covariance function is the basic squared exponential function:

```
k(x,x0) =σ0²*exp(-(x-x0)²/(2*λ²))
```

I've got three hyperparameters to fit over my data : the two parameters from the covariance function (σ and λ), and the σ0 that comes from the assumption that my data is noised.
So I simply need to minimize the negative log likelihood, right?

```
logp(y|X,θ) =1/2*t(y)*C(θ)^(−1)*y+1/2log|C(θ)|+(n/2)*log 2π
```

With `θ=(σ,λ,σ0)` and `C(θ)=K-σ0²*I`

Where K is the covariance matrix obtained applying k over my x vectors.

And the only boundary conditions are that the parameters need to be positive.

But then, no matter what optimization algorithm I use, it fails because it goes straight to -Inf.
After hours during which I thought I couldn't use an optimization algorithm in an appropriate way, I realized that it was in fact quite normal:

My σ0 and my σ go straight to 0 because that gives K=0, C=0, so det(C)=0 and so my negative likelihood becomes -Inf.

That is nonsense of course, the variances that best fit the data can't be 0. But I've got no clue about what I'm doing wrong here, especially since this formulae is written everywhere like that and now I can't figure how optimizing it could give something else than σ=0...

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you're fitting something like a kernel density or kernel density surface, it's entirely possible that there's nothing "wrong" with your code.

It seems to me that the log-likelihood of your fitted surface will increase as your bandwidth approaches zero, with your fit essentially approaching a surface with singularities at your events and zero everywhere else.  From a likelihood perspective, this would constitute a "perfect" fit -- albeit computationally disastrous and inferentially useless.

But on the plus side, it's Friday.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I understand what you say about this likelihood perspective.
But then, that kind of parameters fitting would never work, regardless of data.
I took a look at dozens of course slides, lecture notes and tutorials on the subject on the internet, and each times, the conclusion is that the hyperparameters are easy to find with optimization.
For example, here : https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~mebden/reports/GPtutorial.pdf (see equation 10)
The author finds easily the parameters, whereas I don't understand how the algorithm doesn't give him σ=0.